# How to set time in Netsuite using suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I can set time for **timeofday** type fields both UI/API.

I can set time for the **time** type field **INITIAL TIME BUDGET** as 16:55 using colon(:) separator in UI for **Task**.

I could not set time for that field as below using suitescript,

```
function load(recordType, id) {
   return record.load({
    type: recordType,
    id: id
    });
}

var recordType = "task"
var id = "123"

var objectRecord = load(recordType, id);
objectRecord.setValue("estimatedtime", "16:55");

var updatedId = objectRecord.save({});
```

I get this error

```
You have entered an Invalid Field Value 16:55 for the following field: estimatedtime
```

I tried the following cases,

```
"16:55" - Invalid Field Value
16:55   - UNEXPECTED_ERROR
16.55   - No error, but set as "estimatedtime":"16:33"
```

How to set time for **time** type field?

Comment: It's a number. 0.55 is 55/100ths of an hour which is also  33/60ths of an hour. or  0:33.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Date object. For example, say you pass "13:00", you'll need to do something like:

```
dateStr = "13:00";

d = new Date();
dateParts = dateStr.split(":");
d.setHours(+dateParts[0]);
d.setMinutes(+dateParts[1]);
```

And then:

```
objectRecord.setValue("estimatedtime", d);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set only hour value.
Format has to 24 hours.

objectRecord.setValue("estimatedtime", 23);